# Как исправить эту ошибку при попытке воспроизвести звук в Java?

Tags: java

Когда я запускаю код, выскакивает ошибка:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: a.wav (�� ������� ����� ��������� ����)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
    at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.SunFileReader.getAudioInputStream(SunFileReader.java:117)
    at java.desktop/javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1060)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Код:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File soundFile = new File("a.wav");
            AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(ais);
            clip.setFramePosition(0);
            clip.start();
            Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000);
            clip.stop();
            clip.close();
        } catch (IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException | LineUnavailableException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException exc) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: "file not found" - "файл не найден"

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Почему он может быть не найден, если находится прямо в одной папке с проектом? И почему там вместо нормального текста знаки вопроса?

Comment: @IchBinUser Покажи git репозиторий с этим проектом.

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh как это сделать?

Comment: @IchBinUser Начни [отсюда](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-Git%3F) тогда.

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh Нет, я не глупый и не буду пользоваться гитом, потому что это только всё усложняет.

Comment: @IchBinUser Наоборот, Git многое упрощает и делает разработку в кайф. Без гита тебе сложно будет в дальнейшем.

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh Неправда, мне гит нужен только для создания репозиториев на гитхаб

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй указать не имя файла, а абсолютный путь к файлу [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        
        java.net.URL path = Main.class.getResource("a.wav");
        File f = new File(path.getFile());                  
   
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(f);
```